# Убрать эффект у нажатой кнопки

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

Использую графические кнопки с двумя картинками. Стиль у всех идентичный за исключением фоновых картинок (FontAwesome пиктограммы в PNG формате). Код:

```
<Button x:Name="Close" Content="" ClickMode="Press" Focusable="False" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" UseLayoutRounding="True" Height="42" Width="42" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ButtonCloseNormal.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ButtonCloseHover.png"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <!-- Unknown properties for hidding gray border and scalable effect of background image. -->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

При нажатии на кнопки спустя небольшое время происходит изменение стиля кнопки - добавляется серый бордюр в 2 пикселя и уменьшается размер фоновой картинки.

Подскажите, что добавить в соответствующий триггер `IsPressed` для переопределения и отключения этих эффектов.

Comment: Вам надо править шаблон, а не навешивать еще дополнительные триггеры.

Comment: Т.е. триггер `IsPressed` не нужен, а достаточно переопределить в свойствах кнопки шаблон?

Comment: Ну не просто в свойствах новый шаблон описать, а скорее отредактировать имеющийся. Хотя можно и полностью описать, если вы уверены что справитесь (учтете все нюансы). Для начала в дизайнере кликните правой кнопкой мыши по вашей кнопке и выберите "Edit Template" - "Edit a Copy...", студия добавит шаблон, вот его и редактируйте

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую, теперь уж, на следующей неделе.

Comment: @АндрейNOP нет в VS 2010 такой опции.

Comment: Установите 2015, а лучше 2017ю. Зачем использовать такое старьё?

Comment: Решение найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543790/change-button-image-on-mouse-hover), но иным способом и универсальное для всех кнопок.